# createTextFinder is not a function (Google App script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search

I'm trying to search a range in Google Spreadsheet using App script. I tried creating a text finder:

```
var data = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL").getSheetByName("sheet").getRange(1,1,25,4).getValues();
var textSearch = data.createTextFinder(keyword).findAll();
```

But I keep getting this error: TypeError: data.createTextFinder is not a function

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks

Search for key word and return the values in the cell next (next column) to the matching row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I forgot to remove `.getRange` and `getValues()`, and this worked fine.

Comment: Yip that was the problem